# Regex formatting using grep

Tags: regex, bash, sed, grep

I'm parsing the IDv3 tags of mp3 files for my application and I'm using `id3v2` for it. For example, to get the album name of an mp3 file the command is

```
id3v2 -R sample.mp3 | grep "TALB"
```

which outputs

```
TALB: Album Name
```

But, I want to get only the value of TALB, not the entire line so I passed it to the `sed` as follows

```
id3v2 -R sample.mp3 | grep "TALB" | sed 's/TALB: //'
```

which outputs

```
Album Name
```

So, here are my questions:

1. Can the above mentioned result can be achieved only though `grep`. If so, how can I do it?
2. Even though I got the result I intended to, but when I'm looking for other tags like `TCON` it returns `example.com (255)` in which I need only the `example.com`. So, how can I write regex in the `grep` for this type?

Comment: You cannot do that with `grep` alone. As you've done, you have to use sed or other filter to strip parts of the line out.

Comment: @DiegoSevilla So, with grep I will only get the line?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use Perl-style regex with the `-P` flag:

```
grep -Po '(?<=TALB: ).*'
```

eg:

```
$ echo "TALB: Album Name" | grep -Po '(?<=TALB: ).*'
Album Name
```

`(?<=TALB: )` is a [zero-width look-behind assertion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html). `.*` is the pattern for the rest of the stuff you want to match - in the first case, everything. If you want to match only specific strings after the marker string, as in your second question, then you can change this to suit your specific data.

Comment: Yeah, that's great and how about the second question and please explain the above code.

Comment: Or `grep -Po 'TALB: \K.*'` which might be easier to grasp for someone who is not familiar with look-behind/look-ahead assertions.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a more dynamic approach just using `bash` without externals that you can use to read all/desired tags into variables of the same name for further use. This is faster and gives you all tags that you need without further cost/code.

Another benefit is that this is portable (`<<<` requires `bash 2.05` and `${foo,,}` requires `bash 4` but can easily be dropped, the rest is POSIX). `grep -P`, while *very* handy, is no longer available on OS X for example and thus less suited for scripts if portability among major platforms is a concern.

```
#!/bin/bash

# read line-wise from stdin using colon ':' as additional delimiter.
# what comes before ':' gets stored in $key, what comes after in $value
while IFS=' \t:' read -r key value; do
    # check if the value of $key is a tag that we are interested in
    case ${key} in
        TALB|TCON|TFOO) ;; # $key is one of TALB, TCON or TFOO. let's continue
        *) continue     ;; # otherwise, ignore line and read next line
    esac

    # store $value in the variable named $key, e.g. if
    #   $key == "TCON" and $value == "Album Name"
    # this would create $tcon == "Album Name"
    # (${key,,} converts $key to lowercase during the process)
    read -r "${key,,}" <<< "${value}"
done <<__DATA__
TALB: Album Name
TCON: example.com (255)
TFOO: tfoo
TBAR: tbar
__DATA__

echo "TALB: $talb"
echo "TCON: ${tcon% (255)}"  # strip the trailing " (255)" from $tcon
echo "TFOO: $tfoo"
echo "TBAR: $tbar"
```

.

```
$ ./t.sh
TALB: Album Name
TCON: example.com
TFOO: tfoo
TBAR:
```

`${foo,,}` is `bash 4` notion to expand `$foo` to lowercase to avoid uppercase variable names, but if you don't have `bash 4` you can just drop this and use uppercase names or use `tr` to convert them to lowercase instead.

The `while read line`-idiom is well-explained [here](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001).

Instead of the [heredoc](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/HereDocument) that I used to simulate the output of `id3v2` you would use [process substitution](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ProcessSubstitution) to "pipe the output of `id3v2` into the loop", e.g.

```
while [...]; do
    [...]
done < <(id3v2 -R Idhayam.mp3)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. But, I have no idea what you're doing here especially with `__DATA__` variables and also it seems to be a little bit complex. I am definitely going to use this in shell scripting, but not this much complex.

Comment: @Gowtham It's really not that complex and I added some comments to my code. The `__DATA__` part is explained behind the `heredoc` URL that I gave but you can ignore that if you do as I explain in the very bottom of my answer as I just use it to generate test input instead of actually using `id3v2`.

Answer (score 1):

I think that this is a good job for `awk`:

```
id3v2 -R Idhayam.mp3 | awk -F': ' '/^TALB/ {print $2}'
```

would print the part after the colon. The `-F` switch is used to specify the delimiter, which in this case would be a colon followed by a space. If `TALB` is found at the start of the line, print the second column.

The "TALB" part could be put into a variable, like:

```
id3v2 -R Idhayam.mp3 | awk -F': ' -v i="TALB" '"/^"i"/" {print $2}'
```

If you only want the part before the brackets you could do:

```
awk -F': ' -v i="TCON" '"/^"i"/" { split($2,a,"("); print a[1] }'
```

This uses `split` to create an array `a` which holds the content of the second column, with `(` as the delimeter. Then it prints the first element of that array.

---

If you prefer to use `sed` then there's no need for `grep` as well. You could use regular expressions like this:

```
sed -n 's/^TCON: \([^(]*\).*/\1/p'
```

This only prints the relevant section (the part before the `(`) of the line(s) that start with "TCON". Passing `-n` to `sed` means that it doesn't print each line by default.

- `^TCON` match lines starting with "TCON: "
- `\( \)` capture things in between these brackets (the slashes are needed as escape characters)
- `[^(]` characters that are not a "("
- `*` zero or more of them
- `.*` swallows up the rest of the line

The whole line is substituted for `\1`, which refers to the part that was captured earlier. The `p` means print.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it seems to be more complex than `grep` and `sed`.

Comment: @Gowtham It depends what you regard as complicated. Personally I think that zero-width look-behind assertions are a bit complicated! I have added a sed alternative that addresses your second question

Comment: Yeah, it works, but can you please explain the regex part you used inside.

Comment: @Gowtham I have added an explanation to my answer.